# How can i simulate a distribution of foreign keys to multiple similar tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am about to create an application, that stores information about products. There is a big list of products(with ID, Name, ...) and they have to be distributed to some grocery stores, represented by tables, with equal columns.

```
students:
+-------------------------+
| student_ID | Name | ... |
| ...        | ...  | ... |

store_1
+-----------------------------+
| student_ID | inventory| ... |
| ..         | ...      | ... |

store_2
+-----------------------------+
| student_ID | inventory| ... |
| ..         | ...      | ... |

store_3
...
```

Is there a way to do this better (Without creating 1000 tables for 1000 stores)? I know i could put everything in one table, but if there are 1000s of stores with 1000s of products in each store (=> 1.000.000s of records in one table) it would probably take too long to query. I also thought about creating a json/csv-file for every location, but then there are problems like: How do i sort/query it as fast as in mysql? How can i do sth like 'on delete cascade', ...
Can anybody help me with a better solution/some ideas?

Comment: How is having 1000 tables with 1000 records each better than one table with 1M records?

Comment: *if there are 1000s of stores with 1000s of products in each store (=> 1.000.000s of records in one table) it would probably take too long to query.* That's where indexes come in to play. https://use-the-index-luke.com/ is a good starting spot if you don't know what those are.

Comment: "it would probably take too long to query"...  This is a classic example of premature optimization of an imaginary performance challenge.
It is most likely that overall, having 1000 tables, and the accompanying code complexity to pick which one of these tables to query, and the maintenance nightmare that will follow, will end up causing you 1000 times worse issues than your imaginary performance one. MySQL can handle millions of rows in a table. You are not the first, nor the last to use it... Invest your resources optimizing the data model, schema, and code. Don't assume performance issues.

Comment: @Shawn So if i get this right i should create a table where i define all the links between store_id and product_id, while using an index on store_id, so that it can filter all the products in one store more quickly?

Answer (score 0):

Three tables would do the trick: One for the products and all their attributes (Product_ID, description, vendor codes, etc.); a second table listing the stores (Store_ID, location, sales tax rate, manager, etc.); and finally a table to link the two with a compound primary key of Product_ID, Store_ID that has columns for inventory, price (if different by store, and any other store/product specific attributes).